# Select2 not using my templateResults or templateSelection options

Tags: templates, jquery-select2

I am trying to use the select2 ajax call with templates. I am getting the ajax in just fine but it is not using my template functions.

the ajax data is:

```
[
   {"name":"First thing","otherData":"asdfg"},
   {"name":"Second thing","otherData":"qqerr"},
   {"name":"third thing","otherData":"yerty"},
   {"name":"fourth thing","otherData":"hgjfgh"},
   {"name":"fifth thing","otherData":"fhgkk"}
]
```

the select2 code (which i took a lot from [here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) ) is:

```
FundSearch = {
    create: function (selector, theURL) {
      $(selector).select2({
        ajax: {
          url: theURL,
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 250,
          data: function (params) {
            console.log(params.term);
            return {
              q: params.term, // search term
              page: params.page
            };
          },
          results: function (data, page) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data
            return {
              results: data
            };
          },
          cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        templateResult: formatData,
        templateSelection: formatDataSelection
      });

      function formatData (data) {
          if (data.loading) return data.name;

          markup = "<h1>" + data.name + "</h1>" + "<p>" + data.otherData + "</p>";

          return markup;
        }

        function formatDataSelection (data) {
          return data.name;
        }


    }
};
```

The error I am getting is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined` on line 356 of `select2.js` for Version: 3.5.2.

It seems to me that select2 is not using my templateSelection and templateResults function.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You are looking at the 4.0.0 documentation but are using 3.5.2. [You can still access the 3.5.2 documentation.](https://select2.github.io/select2/)

Specifically, the `templateSelection` and `templateResult` options only exist in 4.0.0. They were called `formatSelection` and `formatResult` in 3.5.2.

Answer (score 3):

In select2 3.5.2., it is "formatResult" (singular, not formatResults)